# Best way to organize data for an Expense app?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, data-structures, code-organization

So I'm trying to create an expense app and I want to be able to sort this data in multiple ways:

- [timeline of every expense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OhWR.png)
- [show the amount spent on each category for monthly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCgNd.jpg), [weekly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceI39.jpg), or [yearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggyYX.jpg) and also [show each expense for each category for monthly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiqCk.png), [weekly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVCNO.png), or [yearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au6m6.png)
- [show the percent spent on each function for monthly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6zGa.jpg), [weekly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJT7z.jpg), or [yearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NfJq.jpg) and also [the amount spent for each category in each function monthly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92JMB.jpg), [weekly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88fUg.jpg), or [yearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9gFg.jpg)

Currently I have an `NSObject Expense` to hold all the information about each expense (cost, date spent, function, category, subcategory, notes, location, & image of receipt)

```
enum Function: String{
    case Personal, Social, Work, Family
}
enum Category: String{
    case General, Personal, House, Food, Transport, Clothes, Fun, Misc
}
enum Subcategory: String{   
    case /*General*/ None, 
        /*Personal*/ Mobile, Medical, Taxes, Insurance, PersonalCare, Gadgets, Pets, Education, Laundry, Fitness, Loan, Vouchers, Subscriptions, 
        /*House*/ Groceries, Rent, Phone, Electricity, Internet, Cable, Water, Repairs, Plants, Mortgage, Electronics, Furniture, Heating,
        /*Food*/ Takeout, Fastfood, DiningOut, Cafe, Drinks, 
        /*Transport*/ Gas, Maintenance, PublicTransport, Taxi, CarLoan, Penalty, Flight, Parking, CarRentals, 
        /*Clothes*/ Shoes, Clothes, Accessories, Underwear, Bags, 
        /*Fun*/ Events, Movies, Recreation, Cultural, Sports, Books, Magazines, Music, Apps, Software, TVShows, 
        /*Misc*/ Gift, Office, Charity, Lodging, Service, Toy
}

class Expense: NSObject {
    var cost: Double
    var date: NSDateComponents

    var function: Function
    var category: Category
    var subcategory: Subcategory

    var note: String
    var location: String
    var receipt: UIImage


    init(amountSpent: Double, date: NSDate){
        self.cost = amountSpent
        //set date
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        self.date = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second, NSCalendarUnit.Nanosecond], fromDate: date)
        //set organization
        self.function = .Personal
        self.category = .General
        self.subcategory = .None
        //set rest of attributes blank
        self.note = nil
        self.location = nil
        self.receipt = nil
    }

    convenience init(amountSpent: Double){
        self.init(amountSpent: amountSpent, date: NSDate()) //set to today's date
    }

    init(amountSpent: Double, date: NSDate, function: Function, category: Category, subcategory: Subcategory){
        self.cost = amountSpent
        //set date
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        self.date = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second, NSCalendarUnit.Nanosecond], fromDate: date)
        //set organization
        self.function = function
        self.category = category
        self.subcategory = subcategory
        //set rest of attributes blank
        self.note = nil
        self.location = nil
        self.receipt = nil

    }
}
```

However this is not an ideal structure b/c if I kept an array of all the expenses, I would have to look through *all* the data every time I wanted to sort the data.

Any suggestions on how I should organize my data/structure my code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unless you're seeing performance issues, there's nothing wrong with how you've structured it.

Comment: @chedabob I haven't implemented that yet so I can't comment on performance issue, but I feel like sorting through all the data would eventually slow down the app? Because the more expense entries I have , the longer the array that I have to scan each time I want to display the data in a certain way

Comment: You're exactly right, but unless you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of elements, sorting and filtering won't present much of a challenge to an iPhone

Comment: I'd benchmark it (XCTest has support for this), and see what kinds of times you get. One optimisation I would make is to change the `receipt` field to some kind of identifier, as if you've got a large number of elements, you'll hit memory issues storing large numbers of `UIImage` objects in memory.